Packet loss and reduced speeds when other switch is 100 mb
I have OPNsense setup on a PC that is connected to a 5 port gigabit switch. The switch is connected to another switch in my roommates room that is an 8 port gigabit switch. Sometimes he kicks his cable and it causes his connection to go to 100 Mb instead of gigabit, and for some reason when this happens and if he is downloading something, it causes my connection on my switch to have very bad packet loss and high latency (300 ms ++). When he replugs it in to fix it to gigabit, and is downloading something, the issue goes away. Shouldn't his switch / connection speed not interfere with mine? Why is this happening? Any device connected to my switch has this issue

My best guess as to why this is happening is called a traffic “bottleneck”, where the packets start to queue up in the switches. The only real fix to bottlenecks to upgrade/ replace faulty equipment.
